# Referencing a variable in template, loaded from Puppet Ruby DSL each loop

Tags: puppet

```
hostclass :class do
  items = scope.lookupvar('items_list')
  items.each do |item|
    file("/etc/init.d/#{item}",
         :content => template(['class/item_init.erb']))
  end
end
```

Having this class written in Ruby DSL, how do I properly reference the `item` variable in the template? I tried `<%= item %>`, `<%= @item %>`, `<%= scope.lookupvar('item')%>` but none of them work - they all return nil.

**UPD**

I've found out that it works if inside the loop I define `$item_name = item` and then reference it as `$item_name` in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that it works if inside the loop I define $item_name = item and then reference it as $item_name in the template.